# join between two tables with more than two columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

Need to join two tables on 4 column

TABLE A
column1 column2 column3 column4
aaa
bbb
ccc
abc
acb
aaa zzz
ccd
ddd
bbc
bbb yyy
ccc zzz
fff xxx
fff
fff zzz
fff     rrr 
fff     rrr ttt

TABLE B
column1 column2 column3 column4
aaa
bbb
gh
abc
gfd
aaa zzz
gfg
ddd
fvgg
bbb ggg
gff zzz
g   xxx
fff
ccc ty
fff     rrr 
fff     bb  ttt

All the rows in table 'A' need to be uniquely identified by the combination of 4 columns
If a column is null then no need of joining with that column.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
SELECT a.column1 AS a_column1,
       a.column2 AS a_column2,
       a.column3 AS a_column3,
       a.column4 AS a_column4,
       b.column1 AS b_column1,
       b.column2 AS b_column2,
       b.column3 AS b_column3,
       b.column4 AS b_column4
FROM dbo.TableA a INNER JOIN dbo.TableB b
    ON a.column1 = b.column1 
   AND a.column2 = b.column2 
   AND a.column3 = b.column3 
   AND a.column4 = b.column4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .....but if any value is null in any of that column then that time join should not happen with that column that too need to be considered .Please answer with that logic too..

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Table1 a INNER JOIN Table2 b 
on a.column1 = b.column1 AND 
a.column2 = b.column2 AND 
a.column3 = b.column3 AND 
a.column4 = b.column4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .....but if any value is null in any of that column then that time join should not happen with that column that too need to be considered .Please answer with that logic too.

Comment: NULL value gets ignored in JOIN i.e. NULL = NULL is always false. Think about NULL as infinite, then INFINITE = INFINITE + 1. So will always be false